# Embed JS code in body field

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Doesn't Drupal 7 block javascript code in body field of the node? I use filter "Full HTML" and still it doesn't work. Maybe I don't load it right, here it is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.text-block:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){
      $('#text-blocks > :first-child').fadeOut(0)
        .next().fadeIn(0)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#text-blocks');
    },
    3000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that when putting jQuery into drupal fields, you have to wrap them in script and jquery tags.

```
<script>
(function ($) {

  // Original JavaScript code.

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: That's right, when I added this JS error `Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function` disappeared. But the script still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be best to enable the PHP filter if you can.  Enable that in the modules section and use it for that specific block.

If you are using a WYSIWYG, you would have to switch it to plain text for the javascript to work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know mechanisms of displaying nodes in drupal but when i removed `$(document).ready(function(){` from my script, it started to work fine.

Comment: The WYSIWYG will probably still strip the javascript when you go back and edit the page. So you should still follow the instructions in my answer.

Comment: WYSIWYG isn't configured for my PHP filter, so it's not a problem. Thanks anyway!